# How can I add Interpolation to get the width for LI?

Tags: html, css, angular, interpolation

I wanted to bring the same value of {{getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable')}} + px to LI width with class having background color but as soon as I am adding same to style.width getting error.

`Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 1`

`<li class="chart__bar" [style.width]="{{getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable')}}">{{getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable')}}</li>`

please suggest how to get the li width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="chart__bar" [ngStyle]="{'width': (getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable')*10)+ '%'}">{{getCount(userObj.assigned_to, 'Applicable')}}</li>
```